# Why espresso needs test method names to start with "test" even though it is using AndroidJunit4 runner?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have been trying to run espresso tests using `AndroidJunit4` runner.
Here is my Test Class.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {
  public MyActivityTest() {
    super(MyActivity.class);
  }
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    getActivity();
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldAssert() {
    onView(withId(someId)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  }
}
```

I have been trying to run this test via `./gradlew connectedCheck` from command line but for some reason it does not recognize this test.
I am able to run this test via Android Studio though.
If I rename my test method from `shouldAssert` to `testShouldAssert` gradle is able to recognize this as a test and runs it successfully.
I am puzzled since in Junit4 style test method names need not start with test.
Anybody has any idea about this?

[EDIT]
Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2') {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your "build.gradle" file?

Comment: added build.gradle config

Answer (score 0):

When running from the command line be sure that gradle is using the jUnit4 runner.

Add the testInstrumentationRunner to the build.gradle file

```
 android {
   defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Without this runner, the default jUnit3 runner will be used which requires test methods to begin with "test"

Comment: I have this config in my build.gradle filr

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, use the @Rule annotation:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MyActivityTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> mActivityRule = 
    new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void shouldAssert() {
    onView(withId(someId)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  }
}
```